# Using tricks to Maximize a Product of Binomial Coefficients $\binom{n}{x} \times \binom{n}{b - ax}$

Tags: probability, optimization, combinations, binomial-coefficients, puzzle

I'm trying to find a solution to the following problem without resorting to brute force:

\begin{equation}
\text{maximize } \binom{n}{x} \times \binom{n}{y}
\end{equation}

subject to the constraints:

\begin{align}
0 \leq x \leq n, \\
0 \leq y \leq n, \\
ax + y = b
\end{align}

where $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$.

A brute force approach I considered was defining:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \binom{n}{x} \times \binom{n}{b - ax}
\end{equation}

Then, I would find the smallest value of $x$ such that the ratio $\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} \leq 1$. However, I am looking for a more elegant and efficient solution.

To give some context, this problem arose from a scenario involving two types of fair coins, $A$ and $B$. There are $500$ coins of type $A$ and $500$ of type $B$. For every head from an $A$ coin, I earn 1 dollar, and for every head from a $B$ coin, I earn 4 dollars. If I know that I have won $1200$ dollars in total, what is the most probable configuration of heads?

Using brute force, I derived the answer to be $238$ heads from the $A$ coins. However, the teacher indicated that we shouldn't resort to the brute force method, as there's a clever trick to address this problem. Is there another method to obtain this result?

[image]
[image]

PS: I suspect the teacher is hinting at a solution that leverages symmetry. For instance, to maximize $\binom{n}{x} \times \binom{n}{b - x}$, the optimal value would be $x = b/2$. If $a > 1$, it introduces an asymmetry between $A$ and $B$.

It reminds me of a similar trick used to maximize $x^3 (9 - 2x)$ without using calculus. We can express this as $2x^3 \left(\frac{9}{2} - x\right) = \frac{2}{3} x^3 (\frac{27}{2} - 3x)$, recognizing that $x + x + x + \left(\frac{27}{2} - 3x\right) = \frac{27}{2} $, which is constant. Equating the terms gives $ x = x = x = \frac{27}{2} - 3x $, which implies $ x = \frac{27}{8} $.

Comment: $-\log f$ is convex on the non-negative reals with a minimum which should be between $0$ and $n$, could you not just use Newton's method? I don't think there is a nice analytic solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using algebra, it would be simpler to solve
$$\log(f(x+1))-\log(f(x))=0$$ and to write, in Mathematica syntax

`F[x_]:=2*LogGamma[1 + n]-Log*Gamma[1 - b + n + a*x] - LogGamma[1 + n - x] - LogGamma[1 + x] - LogGamma[1 + b - a*x]`

and then

`FindRoot[F[x]==F[x+1],{x,x0}]`

where (to be defined somewhere) `x0=(2*b - n)/(2*a)`

Without any solver and coding Newton method, the iterates will be (using your values for $(a,b,n)$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & x_p \\
 0 & 237.500000000 \\
 1 & 237.735764976 \\
 2 & 237.735757882 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$